# createElement(script)/appendChild how to debug added script?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

```
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.innerHTML = layout[i].text;
    document.body.appendChild(js);
```

I am adding a script like that, notice there is no `src`, but `innerHTML` instead, a script is fetched on demand with `XMLHttpRequest`. Unfortunately the script does not appear in the dev tools, not in Chrome not in Firefox.

How to append a script from a source string so that I can still debug it in the devtools?

Comment: I don't understand, how do you fetch a script when src is missing? Or are you looking for an inline script to appear? In this case, what's the content of layout[i].text?

Comment: @lustoykov script source code was fetched with `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: You can add `debugger;` to the script text so it'll pause automatically in devtools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to debug dynamically added scripts in Chrome, you need to append //# sourceURL=test_file_name.js at the end of the script that you want to debug, like below

```
var js = document.createElement("script");
js.type = "text/javascript";
js.innerHTML = layout[i].text + "//# sourceURL=test_file_name.js";
document.body.appendChild(js);
```

Now, if you open the source tab in Dev console, you will find test_file_name.js under the (no domain) section (normally). I just verified it in Chrome version 67.0.X

I believe the same should work on Firefox as well,

Refer these links also,

[Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#breakpoints-dynamic-javascript)

[sourceMappingURL and sourceURL syntax changed](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/06/sourceMappingURL-and-sourceURL-syntax-changed)

**Update :** 
This doesn't work in firefox. There are several bugs created for this issue, but no fix so far, [script tag using sourceURL doesn't appear in debugger sources pane](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1224078)

Comment: Yes, just now found the link to that bug, not sure if there's any workaround